# Upload application to android market with same version name and code

Tags: android

I have created my app in android  and for checking the in-App purchase, i uploaded the app in market as a draft application.Everything i checked regarding the in-app purchase.Now i want to publish my app in the market.Can i use the same version name and version code for that?

Note: I tested my app as a draft application

So any problem for publishing app?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

No issues. Just publish\activate your app and it will be live.  You need to increment the version number every time you upload a new apk though.

Comment: I mean can i use the first version name which i was given already for the draft application which is uploaded ? Like version 1.0 ? Because i  want to publish my app starting with version name 1.0..

Comment: you can use whatever you want for the version name. its purpose is only for user display and can literally be anything you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you have did last publication using debug mode true then you no need otherwise You have to upgrade your version number for every time upload.

Best

V.k